# Сохранение настроек приложения

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, с помощью каких инструментов можно реализовать сохранение настроек приложения в самом файле приложения? Например я упаковал приложение в один файл и хочу хранить настройки приложения в этом файле. Возможно ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, хранить данные прямо в apk не получится, так как он уже скомпилирован и любая запись в него требует наличия root прав на устройстве.

Хранить данные можно либо в `SharedPreferences`, либо в файле на устройстве. Если нужно хранить много однотипной информации используете БД